# Custom URL scheme to open text in whatsapp from mobile browser, newline / line break not working

Tags: javascript, android, html, jquery-mobile, line-breaks

I am using the following code: (jquery)

`window.open("whatsapp://send?text=Hello World!")`

To open and share a message from the mobile browser, this documentation can be found here:
https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/28000012

However, I'd like to add a 'newline' somewhere in the message.

I tried: `\n` `<br>` `<br/>` `&lt;br&gt;` in the message but these do not seem to work properly.

`\n` `\r` only give me a "space" as well as `+`

`&lt;br&gt;` breaks the sentence off.

Anyone that can give me some insight into how I generate a linebreak in the whatsapp message from a (mobile) browser?

Really stuck here!

Comment: try &#10x; or \u0010 perhaps?

Comment: or %0A given that its a URL string

Comment: `&#10x;` cuts off the sentence `\u0010` generates a space same as I encountered with `\n` . However, `%0A` seems to do the job perfectly!
May I ask, is `%0A` Android specific or will it work for iOS as well ?

Comment: Its URL encoding, so it will be standard for all URL's - ios and android both

Comment: Dont forget %20 for the spaces too, also # and & will need special treatment

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Based on the URL scheme I'm pretty sure that %0A is the way to go, you could go as far as %0A%0D...

```
window.open("whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World!%0AAnother%20Word")
```

Most languages will have a method for URL encoding - see this website for an example implementation:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Comment: This is correct, thank you for your help, I'll be accepting your answer as soon as it lets me!

Comment: How to open direct chat of a particular person?

Comment: The interesting case is the space in URL query string which you want to send... I cannot send the message over API which has url with query string with space...